# Redirecting git lfs from global repository to a local one

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a pc with an access to some web repository with lfs (pc_1) and have another pc (pc_2) that has access to pc_1 but not to the web repo. I try to clone the repository from pc_1 to pc_2 via ssh, but with git-lfs I get the error "Error downloading <...>: batch request: missing protocol: """. If my understanding is right, it happens because lfs points to the remote repo and pc_2 doesn't have access to it.

Is it possible to make pc_2 to resolve lfs files not with the web repo, but take them from the repo on pc_2?